# input argument structure for constructor in remix

Tags: solidity, go-ethereum, contract-development, contract-design

how would the structure for an argument to the below constructor look like in remix?

```
constructor(
    uint256[5] memory _a,
    uint256[5] memory _b,
  ) public {...}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remix uses JSON notation for the input, and `uint256[5]` is just an array with a length of 5, so in Remix you can do something like this:

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5], [6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
```